# Redux reducer - object destructuring does not work

Tags: object, ecmascript-6, redux, reducers, destructuring

I'm struggling with object destructuring using this syntax:

```
const { [key]:value, ...allNewUserMsgs } = allUserMsgs
```

where (example)

```
allUserMsgs = {
0 : {number: 0, text: "Those kumquats are nothing more than bees?", is_user_msg: false},
1 : {number: 1, text: "A polite zebra is a wolf of the mind.", is_user_msg: false},
2 : {number: 2, text: "Framed in a different way, a proud lime is a seal of the mind.", is_user_msg: false},
3 : {number: 3, text: "A cooperative kitten is an orange of the mind.", is_user_msg: false}
}

key = 2
```

and in console typing variables by hand i receive correct result where:

```
allNewUserMsgs == {
    0 : {number: 0, text: "Those kumquats are nothing more than bees?", is_user_msg: false},
    1 : {number: 1, text: "A polite zebra is a wolf of the mind.", is_user_msg: false},
    3 : {number: 3, text: "A cooperative kitten is an orange of the mind.", is_user_msg: false}
    }
```

But the problem is, when using the same syntax in Redux reducer I receive same object, without any change.

Here is my app:

```
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/understanding-redux-skypey?path=src/reducers/messages.js:58:35
```

Perhaps, there is a problem with other piece of code, however as you can see other action for adding new message (SEND_MESSAGE in messages.js) works fine (click on the contact to see chat and input form) in right panel.

I have no idea what's wrong. Code seems to be OK, but for some reason does not work.

Comment: I am getting same object even in the browser. See here:https://jsbin.com/dobitikili/edit?js,console

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve here? You're just wanting to delete a message from the users message history, correct?

Comment: Darce, yes - i want to delete user message from the store state. 

I found a way to do it by using lodash library:
`_.omit(allUserMsgs, key)`

Comment: Murli - check this [link](https://cdn.glitch.com/095448e6-467f-47f2-986f-04d39849f1df%2Fimage.png?1536040475735), I'm receiving changed object.